# mat-stepper is not displaying within mat-dialog

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-material2

My mat-stepper was working fine when its was in home component. I wanted it to open on a dialog box so I placed all the codes inside the mat-dialog component but then it is not showing anything inside `<mat-horizontal-stepper>...</mat-horizontal-stepper>`.
My dialog-component is

```
<h2 mat-dialog-title>Add Distributor <button mat-dialog-close style="float:right">X</button></h2>

<mat-dialog-content>
  Hello

  <mat-horizontal-stepper [linear]="true" #stepper="matHorizontalStepper" *ngIf="isAddNewDistributorClicked">
    <mat-step [stepControl]="firstFormGroupDistributor">
      <form [formGroup]="firstFormGroupDistributor">
        <ng-template matStepLabel>Identification</ng-template>
        <mat-form-field>
          <input matInput placeholder="Distributor's Name" formControlName="distributor_name" required >
        </mat-form-field>
        <br>
        <label>Registered On</label>
        <mat-radio-group formControlName="distributor_identification_type" [(ngModel)]="distributor_identification_type" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}"  (change)="distributor_identification_type_changed()" >
          <mat-radio-button value="VAT">VAT </mat-radio-button>
          <mat-radio-button value="PAN">PAN</mat-radio-button>
        </mat-radio-group>
        <br>
        <mat-form-field *ngIf="distributor_identification_type=='VAT'">
          <input matInput placeholder="VAT Registration Number" formControlName="distributor_VAT" type="number" >
        </mat-form-field>
        <mat-form-field *ngIf="distributor_identification_type=='PAN'">
          <input matInput placeholder="PAN Registration Number" formControlName="distributor_PAN" type="number" >
        </mat-form-field>
        <div>
          <button mat-raised-button color="primary" matStepperNext [disabled]="!firstFormGroupDistributor.valid">Next</button>
          <button mat-raised-button color="warn" (click)="onAddNewDistributorCancelled()" style="float:right">Cancel</button>
        </div>
      </form>
    </mat-step>
  </mat-horizontal-stepper>
</mat-dialog-content>
```

I have removed some code inside mat-horizontal-stepper as stackoverflow was telling me I have posted lot of codes than description. but these codes are working fine in my home.component. I just wanted to show it in a dialog box but now it is showing this much only

[image: screenshot]

why is this happening?

While testing through `ng test`
karma says

```
Failed: Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'linear' since it isn't a known property of 'mat-horizontal-stepper'.
1. If 'mat-horizontal-stepper' is an Angular component and it has 'linear' input, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'mat-horizontal-stepper' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
3. To allow any property add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component. .
```

then it says to all the properties.
`NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA` was already there in my app.module.. I have added `CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA` also but no effect

My dialog.module.ts is

```
import { Component, OnInit, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { MatDialogRef, MAT_DIALOG_DATA } from '@angular/material';

@Component({
selector: 'app-add-distributor-dialog',
templateUrl: './add-distributor-dialog.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./add-distributor-dialog.component.css']
})
export class AddDistributorDialogComponent implements OnInit {

    constructor(public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<AddDistributorDialogComponent>,
    @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: any) { }

    ngOnInit() {
    }
    onNoClick(): void {
        this.dialogRef.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you get any error or something similar? Did you debug the app and maybe run a test (unit testing and/or E2E test) for that?

Comment: @k.vincent i have added the test result above. Please have a look and help me

Comment: @ How did you add `CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA` in `app.module.ts`?

Comment: ...and also check the `import` of `mat-horizontal-stepper` etc.

Comment: Did you import `MatStepperModule`? Did you add theming to your app?

Comment: Can you please drop the `dialog.component.ts`code?

Comment: @k.vincent  schemas: [ NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA, CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA ], this is how i added and my entry points are entryComponents: [ AddDistributorDialogComponent, ViewOnMapDialogComponent]

Comment: @edric.. yes i have imported MatStepperModule

Comment: @k.vincent i have updated my question with my dialog.component.ts

Comment: @ArunAmatya Which Angular and Angular Material version are you using?

Comment: @k.vincent "@angular/cdk": "^5.2.4",
    "@angular/common": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/core": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/http": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/material": "^5.2.4",

Comment: @ArunAmatya: Can you try this pls. in `*.component.ts`: `isLinear = true;`. also check [this](https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/7353). Ans you can also try this: ` [linear]="isLinear"`

Comment: @k.vincent.. I tried but it didn't work.. same error.. the link you provided also have no solutions.. Have you tried having mat-horizontal-stepper in mat-dialog?

Comment: Let's continue in [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170068/mat-stepper-is-not-displaying-within-mat-dialog)

Comment: i don't have enough reputation to chat..:(

Answer (score 0):

it is because of mat-horizontal-stepper style. please try following style.

```css
:host ::ng-deep {
  .mat-horizontal-stepper-header-container {
    position: inherit;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is some issue regarding putting stepper inside material dialog. Try to disable animation on stepper:

```
<mat-horizontal-stepper [@.disabled]="true" [linear]="true" #stepper="matHorizontalStepper" *ngIf="isAddNewDistributorClicked">
```